# Georeferencing CIA's Lambert Conformal Conic projection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, georeferencing

I'm trying to load into the QGIS an image generated from the NA [CIA Fact Book PDF](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/graphics/ref_maps/political/pdf/north_america.pdf)  which uses Lambert Conformal Conic Projection, standard parallels 25°N and 77°N. I'd like to work with the exact projection from this PDF and overlay some vector data on top of it.

I think there is something wrong in my workflow. Here is what I've done so far

1. export the PDF to a TIFF file
2. Define a Custom CRS in QGIS:

> +proj=lcc +lat_1=25 +lat_2=77 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs

3. Open the tiff file in georeferencer.  When prompted for CRS, pick the custom defined lcc as above
4. Add 6 or so GCP at the grid intersections
5. Transformation settings: Linear/Nearest Neighbor/Target SRS: select the custom defined as above.
6. Once the image loads into qgis it does not look correct. I've tried Polynomial 2 transform but that didn't fix either.

My understanding is that when the source and dest projection does not change I should be able to use the Liniar transformation.

using QGIS 2.18.

[image]

result in qgis:
[image]

Comment: lon_0 of the map seems to be west of the 100° meridian.

Comment: i missed that, thanks. corrected to -101.64.   What does lat_0 refer to?  may that is wrong as well?

Comment: You're georeferencing to lat/lon, not to LCC. Convert the lat/lon values to the projected CRS you want to use, then georeference the image.